# Stop over of 33 hrs at Hong Kong by flight Cathay Pacific

Tags: transit, airports, hkg, cathay-pacific

I am most likely to travel to LAX from Mumbai in next month by Cathay Pacific air lines. I have lay over of about 33 hrs at Hong Kong. I want to know whether air line will provide to and fro journey and accommodation with food during my lay over? I am traveling in same air lines after 33 hrs.

Answer (score 6):

Cathay Pacific **STPC** (stopover paid by carrier) [rules are here](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/images/NZ/Flyers/Terms_and_Conditions.pdf). They're dated from 2012 but I'm presuming they're still active.

> Passengers are NOT eligible for STPC when transfer in HKG is longer
>   than 24hours.

Since you have booked a stopover rather than a long, but required, connection, it appears you are not eligible.

Comment: Many airlines do permit STPC for stays >24 hours if it's the best possible connection, meaning that your second flight does not operate every day. However, the rules you link to don't mention this, and I'm pretty sure both LAX and BOM are served at least daily.

Comment: @jpatokal I was trying to say that in my answer. The OP didn't book a long connection that was required, i.e. unavoidable. But anyway, even if it were unavoidable to have a 33 hour stopover, CX excludes it from STPC